# Copy data from Postgresql to MySQL

Tags: mysql, copy, postgresql

I have encountered a problem where I need to copy only data from a Postgresql database to Mysql database. I already have the Mysql database with empty tables. By using PGAdmin I got a backup (data only, without database schema). I tried using PSQL tool but it keeps giving segmentation fault which I couldn't fix at the moment. I am using Ubuntu. Any simple help with a guide will be highly appreciated to copy data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer data from PostgreSQL to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378443/transfer-data-from-postgresql-to-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Use postgres COPY, and MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE.

psql will crash because of out-of-memory if you try to display a few millions of rows because it fetches all the data beforehand to determine the column widths for a prettier display. If you intend to use psql to fetch lots of data, disable this.

Comment: Mysql wasn't ready at all for postgres' data format. It can't handle Ts or Fs for booleans, and is complaining about data truncation. Is there a set of args that need to be used with COPY for it to work with mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php

Comment: That converts only DDL commands.There is no corresponding commands produced for psql Copy commands.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to load data into mysql with the postgres client tool.  Use the mysql client tools to manipulate data in the mysql server.

[mysql client programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/programs-client.html)

Answer (score -4):

How can you move data into MySQL if you have errors reading from PSQL? 
Fix the error, then ask this question.