# Transfer data from PostgreSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Hello is there any method to transfer the table layout and data from a Postgres database to MySQL automatic?

I have to migrate the scheme anda data to MYSQL

Answer (score 5):

The easiest would probably be to export the database (schema & data) as SQL using Postgres' [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/app-pgdump.html) utility, then [import](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) the resulting SQL file into MySql.

It's possible that there will be some incompatibilities in the intermediate SQL, but you can almost assuredly take care of these with a find/replace in your favorite text editor.

Comment: More details about export how to export values from PostgreSQL can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5746348/1078641

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do using the "Data Transfer" feature of [Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/). It will not preserve foreign keys though, but the data transfers correctly with the two databases incompatibility issues resolved.